# What distinguishes a colony from multicellular organism?

Tags: cell-biology, zoology, microbiology

I would like to inquire what made biologists conclude that colonies such as the famous *Volvox* is an organism constituted by independent cells as opposed to a multicellular being.

I read that it has something to do with "degree of independence". However, what exactly are the parameters of a colony and the so-called "degree of independence" between cells and how is it different from multicellular beings despite possessing notable differentiation such as the latter?